# FRITZ!Box OS routing protocol supported

Tags: routing, fritzbox

I'm looking to buy a FRITZ!Box wireless router, but downloadable manuals on AVM site doesn't mention anything about supported routing (e.g RIP, RIP v2 or OSPF) protocols.

Anyone with some hands-on experience on this product (or any other FRITZ!OS based router) can send me some info?

Comment: Being primarily made as a residential CPE, I'd guess it supports none of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An useful resource is maybe the Fritz!box community site
http://www.wehavemorefun.de/fritzbox/Main_Page

In spite of being written in German, it may help you in many aspects with respect to Fritz!Box hardware.

Good luck!

Comment: Very useful link (even if I don't know german). It seems that the feature will be supported on beta firmware 7170 ... now every connection on wan port is natted.